# How to apply .less styles to JSX

Tags: reactjs, less

I am working with a project that uses the npm package called `less` and `less-loader`. I have read through the documentation, but I am still not following how it works exactly.

Taking a look at a sample in the project, there is a `Lists.tsx` file that imports a less file but it does it in a way that is not familiar to me:

```
import {b} from './Lists.less;
```

That `b` is not coming from the `Lists.less` file itself, it's coming from a `styles.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '*.css' {
  const styles: any;
  export = styles;
}

declare module '*.less' {
  export const b: (...args: unknown[]) => string;
}

declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

The way this is all applied in this project is something like this:

```
<div className={b()}></div>
```

With the less file having something like:

```
.ReadAndAgreeTerms {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

But when I try to apply the same pattern to another file, in console I get:

```
Cannot find name 'b'
  <div className={b('items')}>
     <Text className={b('name')}>{items.name}, </Text>
     <Text className={b('specialties')}>{items.specialties}</Text>
  </div>
```

The corresponding less file I manually created looks like so:

```
.items {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.specialties {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Super unclear what is supposed to be happening here for the styling to take place as I also notice the project does not pass strings into the `b()`, it just passes the `b()` into a `className={}` and it knows how to apply the style.

I renamed the less file to show:

```
.ComponentProvidersInformation {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

&__name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

&__specialties {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I am not getting any errors, but the styling is not taking in a way that looks anything like what it looks like with inline style:

```
<div className={b()}>
  <Text classname={b('name')}>{item.name}, </Text>
  <Text classname={b('specialties')}>{item.specialties}, </Text>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `less` library is nuanced in how it uses class selectors. On the `filename.less` file you need to write it like this:

```
.ComponentSelector {
  &__name {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  &__nextOne {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
  }

  &__anotherOne {
   font-size: 12px; 
  }
}
```

And the `.tsx` file was correct like so:

```
<div className={b()}>
  <Text classname={b('name')}>{item.name}, </Text>
  <Text classname={b('nextOne')}>{item.specialties}, </Text>
 <Text classname={b('anotherOne')}>{item.address}, </Text>
</div>
```

I hope this helps someone who is as unfamiliar with `less` as I was.